# C++, Pulling signed-multi-digit-integers from a char array

Tags: c++, arrays, integer, character

(C++ on Linux, KiTTy)

(HOMEWORK)

Hi, new to the website here.
I'm looking to (as the title suggests) pull multi-digit and single-digit integers out of an array of characters.

Example input would look like this:

1234+-5000 + 65 =

The data would be stored in an array as such...

[ 1 ][ 2 ][ 3 ][ 4 ][ + ][ - ][ 5 ][ 0 ][ 0 ][ 0 ][' '][ + ]['  '][ 6 ][ 5 ][' '][ \0 ]......[MAX_STR_LEN]

The output needs to be the sum of 1234,-5000, and 5. Things to consider are:

1. I must create any helper functions that would be used to process the information.
2. This will be converted later into Motorola 68k ASM language (Manually).

Any suggestions? Thanks a bunch!

UPDATE: Solved! Thanks everyone! I used the Doctor's advice.

Comment: Welcome to SO: What have you tried?

Comment: Check out http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/str/. You can insert the numeric value there and get the string

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using 'Strings', simply because I need to convert the code into assembly language after I can do the logic aspect in C++. If we can stick to just using this array of characters, that would be best. I need to be able to code every little detail myself, otherwise the translation from C++ to Assembly will be very difficult. Right now, my code can access the index of the first char of the integer. I'm thinking of doing something like a simple loop that would traverse the characters of the integer, until it reached a space or an operator sign, counting the chars.

Comment: A function I created called skip_whitespace, would traverse the index of the array to the location of the next integer character or operator. The problem is, how many digits is that integer? Is it negative? That's the part I'm really stuck on.

Comment: Needing to manually convert to assembly makes this an assembly question. And if this is homework, it's only reasonable to say so and note such arbitrary restrictions. By the way, there's a handy dandy tool for converting C++ to assembly language called a compiler, you haven't actually said you can't use it… and if I were you, I'd still simply compile a reasonable C++ program, and annotate the disassembled result (mostly function calls to the standard library).

Comment: Yes, this is homework - I will edit that in. And yes, I know that the compiler does what our instructor wants us to do by hand. I'll remember for the future to give more specifics, but I thought this was decent for my first time using the site. Thanks again for all the input guys.

Answer (score 1):

i'd make two functions.

a) one that separates the char array into several char[] each with only one of the numbers. should be straight forward, just walk through the array, when you find a number start copying, when you find a separation token stop (i.e. + or - or ' ') and skip to the next one.

b) then a second function that takes a char array with ascii representation of one number and converts it to an int. easy right? so for char[] of length 3 for example char[2] + char[1] * 10 + char[2] * 100; (assumption here is int of ascii '1' is 1, '2' = 2 - if not make a look up table to convert)

also have an if statement to make it negative if there is a '-' char in position 0...

then add them. done.